# Facebook SDK 3.0 for iOS Logout Button Image

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk, logout

I've installed the [Facebook SDK 3.0](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/) for iOS and I need to implement logout flow.

Where is the resources bundle with the logout button image ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have FBConnect.bundle file then you can see the image contebt of fb their. just right click on FBConnect.bundle and click on show package content which shows all data in that bundle in which you get the "LogoutNormal.png", "LogoutPressed.png" which you can use in your code

Comment: Is FBConnect.bundle part of SDK 3.0 ?

Comment: @jkigel i think it's not part of SDK3.0. it's a part of old sdk's of facebook

Comment: Found it ! https://github.com/search?q=fbconnect&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Everything&language=Objective-C


Thanks!